# Selections in custom plugins in mpld3 -- Making a slider

Tags: javascript, d3.js, matplotlib, mpld3

I'm trying to implement a slider in mpld3, much like [this previous question](https://github.com/jakevdp/mpld3/issues/79).

I'm trying to build off of the [draggable points example](http://mpld3.github.io/examples/drag_points.html) to do this. I'm having a bit of trouble understanding how the following bit of code works:

```
function dragged(d, i) {
      d[0] = obj.ax.x.invert(d3.event.x);
      d[1] = obj.ax.y.invert(d3.event.y);
      d3.select(this)
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + [d3.event.x,d3.event.y] + ")");
    }
```

In particular, what does `this` refer to in this context. I originally thought that I could replace `d3.select(this)` with something like `d3.select("#"+foo)` where `foo = this.props.id`  (at the top of the `draw()` function). But this doesn't work, as shown in [this notebook](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/ahwillia/notebooks/blob/master/mpld3/old/2014_09_06/DragPoints.ipynb) I made. (The second piece of code doesn't allow you to drag the red dots around).

In case what I'm trying to do isn't clear... have a look at [this notebook](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/ahwillia/notebooks/blob/master/mpld3/old/2014_09_06/Two_Subplot_Slider.ipynb). I've made a plugin that allows the red square (the slider) to be dragged horizontally. What I would like to do is make dragging the red dot change the position of the blue dot. So I want to do something like:

```
function dragged(d, i) {
      d[0] = obj.ax.x.invert(d3.event.x);
      sliderPosition = obj.ax.x(d[0]);
      targetPosition = obj.ax.x(-d[0]); // inverted sign
      d3.select("#redsquare")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + [sliderPosition,sliderObj.ax.y(d[1])] + ")");
      d3.select("#bluedot")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + [targetPosition,targetObj.ax.y(d[1])] + ")");
    }
```

The intended behavior for this simple example is to have the blue dot move in the opposite direction of the red square when it is dragged. The question is, what do I put in place of `"#redsquare"` and `"#bluedot"`?

Many thanks.

Comment: It would be great if this were tagged `mpld3`, so could someone with enough SO power to add a tag consider doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know a hacky way to do this. Instead of `d3.select(this)`, you can find the specific element you are interested in the `obj` element array as follows:

```
      d3.select(obj.elements()[0][i])
```

There must be a prettier way, though.